# How to show syntax error for C# in codemirror?

Tags: c#, angularjs, codemirror, code-editor, ui-codemirror

I have looked into the addons for lint and hint in codemirror, but they only support a couple of languages. I am using angularjs to implement codemirror C# editor. How can I show syntax errors for C# language using codemirror like this image?

[image]

Comment: _id is to show how the error should show up